# PHP How do big websites redirect safely to the previous page after logging in for example

Tags: php, security, session, redirect, header

I have been browsing and didn't find a clear answer that ensures me what the best and most secure way of doing this is.

```
<?php
// updatePageInfo.php
session_start();
$root = "http://localhost/";
if(isset($_SESSION['currentPage']))
{
    $_SESSION['previousPage'] = $_SESSION['currentPage'];
}
$_SESSION['currentPage'] = $root . urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
?>


<?php
// login.php
if(isset($_SESSION['previousPage']))
{
    header("location: ".$_SESSION['previousPage']);
    exit();
}
?>
```

Is this the right way of safely redirecting the user to the previous page?

Comment: You can just pass the url as a query parameter and because you should only redirect to your own domains there shouldnt be a problem. Or just use session to store the url.
The URL itself is not the issue here but the fact that you are exposing your servers document root path in it (which is not a valid url by the way).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Do you mean that I can do it this way, but I don't have to use the urlencode function?

Comment: You can do it this way using the localhost (domain). The urlencode is not needed because  it encodes all url parts that would be interpreted by the browser and would be used if you for example pass the url as a query parameter.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I will remove it from my code! :)
Apart from that is it fine how I receive the url and store them in sessions?